# /me/followings/{id} results in 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: ruby, soundcloud

I am using the Official SoundCloud API Wrapper for Ruby (`soundcloud` from https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-ruby) to access SoundCloud API. Oauth is in use and correctly set up. I am able to access `/me/activities` and other `/me/...` resources. Upload sounds, query tracks, comments, etc. successfully.

However, when I try to access a specific following (by id), with the following API call, I get a 401 Unauthorized error:

```
api_response = @soundcloud.get("/me/followings/#{params[:id]}")
```

Query for list of followings works fine:

```
api_response = @soundcloud.get("/me/followings")
```

Any insights on why this could be happening? I assume the soundcloud gem attaches oauth_token/client_id to the API call appropriately, as it does for other resources.

**Addition**:

In a clone of https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-ruby, this can be reproduced with this `RSpec` test:

```
require 'helper'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  WebMock.allow_net_connect!
end

describe SoundCloud do
  context 'initialized with access_token' do
    subject {
      SoundCloud.new(:access_token => ENV['ACCESS_TOKEN'],
                     :client_id => ENV['CLIENT_ID'],
                     :client_secret => ENV['CLIENT_SECRET'])}

    describe "#get /me" do
      it "returns authenticated user details" do
        resp = subject.send(:get, '/me')
        # pp resp.inspect
        expect(resp.kind).to eq('user')
      end
    end
    describe "#get /me/followings" do
      it "returns authenticated user followings" do
        resp = subject.send(:get, '/me/followings')
        # pp resp.inspect
        expect(resp).to be_an Array
        expect(resp[0].kind).to eq('user')
      end
    end
    describe "#get /me/followings/#{ENV['TEST_ID']}" do
      it "returns authenticated user following for id #{ENV['TEST_ID']}" do
        resp = subject.send(:get, "/me/followings/#{ENV['TEST_ID']}")
        # pp resp.inspect
        expect(resp.kind).to eq('user')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Use the following script to run the test:

```
#!/bin/bash

export CLIENT_ID='Your Client ID'
export CLIENT_SECRET='Your Client Secret'
export ACCESS_TOKEN='Your Access Token'
export TEST_ID='Id of someone you follow'

echo CLIENT_ID: $CLIENT_ID
echo CLIENT_SECRET: $CLIENT_SECRET
echo ACCESS_TOKEN: $ACCESS_TOKEN
echo TEST_ID: $TEST_ID

echo '------'

ruby -S rspec spec/followings_spec.rb
```

After the test runs, the last test "#get /me/followings/#{ENV['TEST_ID']}" will fail, when it should not - unless my expectations are wrong.

Comment: I have the same problem here. The endpoint doesn't seem to respond.